# Visual Studio cannot connect to sharepoint site

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-addin

I have spent many hours at this issue and still unable to fix it:

I read somewhere that one cannot deploy apps to sharepoint using the "system account", so I:

1. Created a new account "admin1" in Active Directory.
2. "admin1" is a member of "Administrators" and "WSS_ADMIN_WPG"
3. "admin1" has "dbowner" rights of "WSS_Content" SQL database.
4. "admin1" is site administrator
5. "admin1" is farm administrator

Still, creating a new SharePoint 2013 App in Visual Studio says:

> Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: `http://xxx/`. Make sure that the Site URL is valid and that the current user has the necessary permissions to access the site.
>
> Additional information: the local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm.

And I have executed those PowerShell commands for creating an app isolation domain on MSDN.

Exactly how does one deploy an app to an on premise SharePoint server?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check.

- Check the Host file on sharepoint server and see any mapping over their?
- Open Sharepoint Shell and execute Add-SPShellAdmin  command.
- Also Try to add Admin1 as sysadmin on SQL server.
- If you made changes and did not reboot the server, please reboot the server and try again.

Also take a look on this [technet blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timquin/archive/2013/01/22/setting-up-visual-studio-2012-for-sharepoint-2013-development-offline.aspx).

Comment: Adding the user to SQL server fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

One of the majour reason is **User rights**.
Current loge-in user may not have the full/Administrator level rights/access.
So, Right Click on the => Visual Studio => **Run with Different User** and then the issue will be solve.
This is worked for me.
Hope this may help to others!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are developing from the box that SharePoint is installed on.  If you aren't on one of the WFE you can't deploy full trust solutions via Visual Studio.

The other post also mentions the hosts file.  Make sure you check that and that you have the domain of your SharePoint Web Application mapped in there.  This file is typically located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.`

Remember when editing this that you'll need to run the text editor as administrator or your changes may not save.  You'll need a line in there that looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       http://mydomain/
```